# Why doesn't a backward wave exist?

Tags: optics, waves, interference, geometric-optics, huygens-principle

[Huygens principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens%E2%80%93Fresnel_principle) says every point of wavefront emit wavelet in all directions. Then why does a back ward wave not exist? Can any expert tell real answer? On different sites I get different and contradictory answer.

I am asking question from my class 12 book. It says " Huygens argued that the amplitude of the secondary wavelets is maximum in forward direction and zero in the backward direction; by making this adhoc assumption, Huygens could explain the absence of backwave. However, this adhoc assumption is not satisfactory and the absence of the backwave is really justified from more rigorous wave theory."

What justification is given by wave theory?

answer explained by Marty green on
[Is Wikipedia wrong about Huygens-Fresnel Principle?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/219793/)

is different from answer given by Acuriousmind on

[How does Huygens Principle incorporate the unidirectional property of a traveling wave?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/203105/)

Which is correct?

Comment: Are you asking why wave always travel in one direction? or Why there is no wave travel in opposite direction?

Comment: Did my question help you?

Comment: @user36790 : No, sorry. answer given refers to some 1d or 2d. my question is different.

Comment: What? Then probably you've not understood Floris' answer. The question is same though.

Comment: @user36790 i have read the book that he is referring to (as he is also from india just like me)...the book doesn't take into account so advance calculations...so he is asking for a bit simple explaination that his and my mind can digest.

Comment: yes the question is same. But I want some other answer. I need to known why do they not come back   . But answer you gave deals with dimensions and water.

Comment: The answer given in the question the OP's question supposedly duplicates does not answer the question at all. It is completely wrong to say that 'this question already has an answer'. The answer given was never accepted, and for good reason. The OP is right to not accept your shutting down the question. If you look in the comments of the original question you linked, you will see that the question was not answered. The reverberation that exists in even dimensions is  distinct from backwards waves. This questions actually has an answer, and it has not been given yet.

Comment: @Anubhav Goel: Concerning your last additions and links asking which answer is correct -- neither are correct. I have put the correct answer on both pages.

Comment: @Wapiti Where did your answer go?

Comment: See  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340085346  which shows how the backward wave is eliminated.

Comment: The wave function in a region containing no sources, due to "primary" sources _outside_ that region, is _as if_ the primary sources had been replaced by a certain distribution of "secondary" sources on the boundary surface of that region. And the secondary sources turn out to have a directionality that suppresses "backward" secondary waves. I have tried to show this from first principles in "[Consistent derivation of Kirchhoff's integral theorem and diffraction formula and the Maggi-Rubinowicz transformation using high-school math](https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.7205781)".

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't a backward wavefront exist?

It exists. See the attached picture.

[image]
[Source](http://www.mysearch.org.uk/website3/html/32%20Huygens'%20Principle_.htm)

Comment: Sorry! I wanted to ask about a backward wave.

Comment: This is silly. If the backwards wave existed then you would hear echoes every time somebody talked, and you would see a lightbulb continue to glow after it was turned off (among other things). You can draw a picture, but it proves nothing.

Comment: @Wapiti: paradaillan is correct actually; check the pic. But it doesn't answer the question unfortunately due to possible misinterpretation of the question.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the picture. Like I said it proves nothing. Would YOU take the picture as proof the backwards wave exists?

Comment: The figure shows that there is a "backward" solution. Which is true as far as it goes, but any given, physical wave only exhibits one solution at a time, which is what the question asks about.

Comment: I don't think you prove things in physics. the picture at least suggest that it is possible to do experiment.

Comment: @dmckee; This figure appears to show a portion of a spherical shell source.  A complete spherical shell source would have simultaneously an outward expanding wave ('forward wave') and also an inward converging wave ('backward wave')--isn't that true?

Comment: @user45664 It's true that an isotropic shell source would have both inward going and outward going waves, but I don't interpret the figure that way.

Comment: @pardaillan; How should your figure be interpreted?

Comment: see https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316994209