# Mathematically prove that wavefronts don't travel in the opposite direction

Tags: optics, waves, huygens-principle

While it can be analytically proved that wavefronts travel forward, how do we mathematically prove if wavefronts travel forward and not backward? I have read that it may be derived from $1-\cos(a)$ where $a$ is the angle. Since $\cos 180^{\circ}$ is $-1$ therefore $1 - 1$ equals zero. What is the analytical explanation?

Comment: This is true only in an odd number of spatial dimensions, such as one for a string or three for light and sound. In an even number of dimensions wavefronts moves both forward and back, as is easy to see by observing waves on a  surface of water. Here is the proof: https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath242/kmath242.htm

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/203105/how-does-huygens-principle-incorporate-the-unidirectional-property-of-a-travelin